# Using bSearch to sort ints read in from file

Tags: java, bsearch

I can not figure out what should be in place of the "mid" in the last line, can anyone help?

```
static int bSearch(int[] a, int count, int key)
{
    /* Y O U R  C O D E  H E R E */

    int hi = count;
    int lo = 0;
    int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;

    while(lo <= hi)
    {
        mid = (hi + lo) / 2;

        if(key < a[mid])
            hi = mid - 1;
        else if(key > a[mid])
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }

    return -(mid+1);
}
```

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.binarySearch0%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: have a look at my solution, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Why can't you just return -1 to indicate an error?

Comment: There needs to be some sort of encoding/decoding there, returning -1 doesnt sort the numbers that are being read in at all.